# Oauth for Connect-auth for www.500px.com

Tags: node.js, oauth

I'm trying to extend connect-auth (https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth) to connect to http://www.500px.com oauth, but am having issues and can't find a way to debug other than console.log.

1. I added a strategy five00px.js ( can't name a variable 500px ) as per below, which is a copy of twitter.js strategy with some string substitution.
2. I keep getting Invalid OAuth Request

   Error retrieving the OAuth Request Token: {"statusCode":401,"data":"Invalid OAuth Request"}
3. I can't really see the OAUTH request as it's in HTTP.

Any idea ?

```
    // five00px.js
    /*!
 * Copyright(c) 2010 Ciaran Jessup <ciaranj@gmail.com>
 * MIT Licensed
 */
var OAuth= require("oauth").OAuth,
    url = require("url"),
    http = require('http');

module.exports= function(options, server) {
  options= options || {}
  var that= {};
  var my= {};

  // Construct the internal OAuth client
  my._oAuth= new OAuth("https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/request_token",
                         "https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/access_token", 
                         options.consumerKey,  options.consumerSecret, 
                         "1.0A", options.callback || null, "HMAC-SHA1");
  console.log('1');
  // Give the strategy a name
  that.name  = "five00px";

  // Build the authentication routes required 
  that.setupRoutes= function(app) {console.log('2setupRoutes');
    app.use('/auth/five00px_callback', function(req, res){console.log('3five00px_callback');
      req.authenticate([that.name], function(error, authenticated) {console.log('4authenticate');
        res.writeHead(303, { 'Location': req.session.five00px_redirect_url });
        res.end('');
      });
    });
  }

  // Declare the method that actually does the authentication
  that.authenticate= function(request, response, callback) {console.log('5authenticate');
    //todo: if multiple connect middlewares were doing this, it would be more efficient to do it in the stack??
    var parsedUrl= url.parse(request.originalUrl, true);
    this.trace('parsedUrl=' + request.originalUrl);

    //todo: makw the call timeout ....
    var self= this;
    if( request.getAuthDetails()['500px_login_attempt_failed'] === true ) {
      // Because we bounce through authentication calls across multiple requests
      // we use this to keep track of the fact we *Really* have failed to authenticate
      // so that we don't keep re-trying to authenticate forever.
      delete request.getAuthDetails()['500px_login_attempt_failed'];
      self.fail( callback );
    }
    else {
      if( parsedUrl.query && parsedUrl.query.denied ) {
        self.trace( 'User denied OAuth Access' );
        request.getAuthDetails()['500px_login_attempt_failed'] = true;
        this.fail(callback);
      }
      else if( parsedUrl.query && parsedUrl.query.oauth_token && request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token_secret"] ) {
          self.trace( 'Phase 2/2 : Requesting an OAuth access token.' );
          my._oAuth.getOAuthAccessToken(parsedUrl.query.oauth_token, request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token_secret"],
                                function( error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, additionalParameters ) {
                                  if( error ) {
                                    self.trace( 'Error retrieving the OAuth Access Token: ' + error );
                                    request.getAuthDetails()['500px_login_attempt_failed'] = true;
                                    this.fail(callback);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    self.trace( 'Successfully retrieved the OAuth Access Token' );
                                    request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token_secret"]= oauth_token_secret;
                                    request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token"]= oauth_token;
                                    var user= { user_id: additionalParameters.user_id,
                                               username: additionalParameters.screen_name }
                                    self.executionResult.user= user; 
                                    self.success(user, callback)
                                  }
                                });
      }
      else {


        my._oAuth.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_authorize_url, additionalParameters ) {
          if(error) {
            self.trace( 'Error retrieving the OAuth Request Token: ' + JSON.stringify(error) );
            callback(null); // Ignore the error upstream, treat as validation failure.
          } else {
            self.trace( 'Successfully retrieved the OAuth Request Token' );
            request.session['500px_redirect_url']= request.originalUrl;
            request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token_secret"]= oauth_token_secret;
            request.session.auth["500px_oauth_token"]= oauth_token;
            self.redirect(response, "https://api.500px.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" + oauth_token, callback);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return that;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to use OAuth 1.0 (instead of 1.0A)

```
 my._oAuth= new OAuth("https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/request_token",
                     "https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/access_token", 
                     options.consumerKey,  options.consumerSecret, 

                     "1.0", 

                      options.callback || null, "HMAC-SHA1");
```